# Discord bot that gives a user role when I react with emoji

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been working on a verification bot that gives members "Verified" role when I react on their pictures.

I found 1 main issue, the bot works fine but if anyone else reacted aswell the bot will simply keep spamming with message, is there a way to fix this point so that the first react only on the post will send verification message ?

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == :
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Verified')
            role2 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Not-Verified')

            if role is not None:
                msg = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
                member = msg.author
                channel = await member.create_dm()
                if member is not None:
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    await member.remove_roles(role2)
                    await channel.send("You have been Verified!")
                    print('done')
                else:
                    print('member not found')
```

Comment: `if member is not None and role not in member.roles:` ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply check if the user already has the verified role:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == :
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Verified')
            role2 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Not-Verified')

            if role is not None:
                msg = await bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
                member = msg.author
                channel = await member.create_dm()
                if member is not None and role not in member.roles:
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    await member.remove_roles(role2)
                    await channel.send("You have been Verified!")
                    print('done')
                else:
                    print('member not found or user already has role')
```